# How can I send an email with a list of all filenames from current upload?

Tags: php, json, fine-uploader

I have implemented Fine Uploader and have everything working correctly. I even have added the ability to email a filename upon upload. However, if there are multiple files being uploaded in one session, it will send a separate email for all those files. Is there a way to send one email with all the filenames?

**PHP File (how I am getting the filename and sending email currently)**

```
require_once "handler.php";


$uploader = new UploadHandler();

$uploader->allowedExtensions = array(); // all files types allowed by default

$uploader->sizeLimit = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // default is 10 MiB

$uploader->inputName = "qqfile"; // matches Fine Uploader's default inputName value by default

$uploader->chunksFolder = "chunks";
    $method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
if ($method == "POST") {
    header("Content-Type: text/plain");


    if (isset($_GET["done"])) {
        $result = $uploader->combineChunks("Digital_Uploads");
    }
    // Handles upload requests
    else {
        // Call handleUpload() with the name of the folder, relative to PHP's getcwd()
        $result = $uploader->handleUpload("Digital_Uploads");

        // To return a name used for uploaded file you can use the following line.
        $result["uploadName"] = $uploader->getUploadName();

    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}

    $to      = 'xxxxxx@xxxxx.com';  // give to email address 
$subject = 'New Photo Submitted';   //change subject of email 
$from    = 'xxxxxx@xxxxx.com';      // give from email address 
$message = '<html><body><h1>A file has been uploaded for scheduling</h1><br>';
$message .= '<h3>'.$result["uploadName"].'</h3></body></html>';
$headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers));
```

**Uploader Script (using button to send all files when user is ready)**

```
<script>
        var manualUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger'),
            template: 'qq-template-manual-trigger',
            request: {
                endpoint: '/Digital/endpoint.php'
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: '/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            autoUpload: false,
            debug: true


        });


        qq(document.getElementById("trigger-upload")).attach("click", function() {
            manualUploader.uploadStoredFiles();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: where is the code of `$uploader` ?

Comment: It's above the code I included...sorry, I didn't want to take up the whole screen with all of the code. I'll add it above.

Comment: Does the js upload all files at once or individually ?

Comment: I believe it is doing it individually, but concurrently? If that makes sense. The progress bar runs on all files but they complete at different times. I'm not sure if the key is to make the files upload all at once through js or if it's in the php code to be able to get all the files that were uploaded. If they uploaded all at once, would $result["uploadName"] show all the filenames?

Comment: The JavaScript is sending individual parallel upload requests to the server."**If they uploaded all at once, would `$result["uploadName"]` show all the filenames?**" In your case no, because every file is handled as a different request, so, `$result["uploadName"]`, will only have one filename each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have set `autoUpload` to `false`. This usually means that your users will select all files to be uploaded, and then click a button to begin the upload process for all selected files. So, perhaps you can assume that, once the last file has been sent successfully in this batch, you can go ahead and send your email.

Two things you should do:

1. Register [an `onAllComplete` callback handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#allComplete), and make a request to your server when Fine Uploader triggers this event. At this point, you can assume that all files in the batch have been sent to the server.
2. Include some information needed to uniquely identify the batch of files. This identifier can be sent with each file by calling [the `setParams` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#setParams) and including this param as a JavaScript object.

An alternative to #2 above is to instead include a list of all Fine Uploader-assigned UUIDs in the batch with your `onAllComplete` request. The `onAllComplete` event handler will be passed two params: an array of successfully uploaded IDs, and an array of unsuccessfully uploaded IDs. You can then get UUIDs for each file by using [the `getUploads` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getUploads).

Comment: Ok...so I think this is the direction I was trying to go, but just haven't been able to make it happen. I am willing to experiment and try things, but any examples or anything you can show me to put me in the right direction of how to implement this using the getUpload method? Do I just add this below debug: true in my current script? callbacks: {
        onAllComplete: function(succeeded) {
  
   var files = manualUploader.getUploads({
                      
       
                 });
     
    
  }
  }. From there I am stuck :( Sorry I am new at this and feel so close but just can't get it

Comment: In your `onAllComplete` handler you must make an ajax request to your server, which will then trigger an email. How you group the files is a relatively easy problem to solve with many solutions. I've provided two Fine Uploader related approaches, but you could just as easily make use of cookies, or something else, to group files.

Comment: would you be willing to show me an example of how this would be structured. Sorry, I am just not able to figure it out. I am new at this and I don't like things to be just done for me, but I am struggling to get this part for some reason. I am wanting to use the onAllComplete and getUploads methods. I've tried creating an alert just to see if I am getting the array of names but it either comes pops up blank or [object][Object], so obviously I am not doing something right. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've updated my script above to show what I currently have - it will show me the id (0,1,etc) but that is the only thing I have been able to get successfully. I was looking at [Simple status query](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/statistics-and-status-updates.html)

Comment: You should avoid changing your question based on answers to the question. I would suggest rolling back your edit and opening a new question. The process for solving this is as follows: 1. Contribute onAllComplete handler. 2. Make ajax request to server in this handler when it is called.

Answer (score 1):

You've a couple of options to achieve what you want.

1 - Remove the email part from your `php` code and create an array in the `javascript`code to keep track of the file names, then, when all the files are uploaded, use `javascript` to make a post or get request with all the filenames to a different `php` file that contains the mail code.
This way, you only send one email and not a bunch of them.

---

2 - Another option is to remove the `javascript` code and let php handle all the uploads, also create an array to keep track of the file names, when all the uploads are finished, send the email.

Comment: Ok, so option 1 sounds like the way that I would want to go. The documentation shows that I can get filenames with an "onSubmitted" callback. Sorry, I'm learning my way through this and really appreciate your help. Would I use something like this to get the array? callbacks: {
        onSubmitted: function(id, name) {
  
   var files = fineUploader.getUploads({
                      status: ['submitted']
                 });
     
  }
  }   Or do you have an example of how I would post the array to the php file? I'm assuming I would use the request command like in my original javascript?

Comment: @CCOdmm Please see my answer for information on how to accomplish this with Fine Uploader's API and event system.

Comment: I'd take a look at @ray answer because it specifically talk about the api you're using. My answer if more of a general approach.